# Pandas - random selection within group until threshold reached

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having trouble randomly selecting from groups, so that my selection reaches a certain cumulative threshold (a value of 20) of a variable (FoV) in the dataframe. The df looks like this:

[image: df]

Currently, I have tried the following, with no success:

```
df_sample_grouped = df_sample.groupby('SAMPLE_ID')
FOV_m2 = 0
obid = []
for name, group in df_sample_grouped:
        for row_index, row in df_sample_grouped.iterrows():
            if (FOV_m2 + i[1]['FOV_m2']) <= 20:
                FOV_m2 += i[1]['FOV_m2']
                obid.append(i[1]['SAMPLE_ID'])
        print(obid)
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
[69 rows x 15 columns](
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-b5c0d6a1c0fa>", line 8, in <module>
    for row_index, row in df_sample_grouped.iterrows():

  File "C:\Users\JH11\Anaconda3\envs\openCV\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 752, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this :

```
df_sample_grouped = df_sample.groupby('SAMPLE_ID')
FOV_m2 = 0
obid = []
memory = {}
for name, group in df_sample_grouped:
    for row in group.sample(frac=1).iterrows():
        if (FOV_m2 + row[1]['FoV']) <= 20:
            FOV_m2 += row[1]['FoV']
            obid.append(row[1]['Phot_No'])
    
    memory[name] = obid
    obid = []
    FOV_m2 = 0


print(memory)
```

In the variable `memory`, you will have a dict with the keys as "SAMPLE_ID" which return list of Phot_No such as the total of FoV from these Phot_No do not go beyond 20.

One Note : `.sample(frac=1)` is used to shuffle the dataframe to add randomness

Have a nice day,

Gabriel :)

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriel - that solution is perfect!